# Sometimes fails to create heap object (Eigen with custom structure)

Tags: runtime-error, alignment, runtime, heap-memory, eigen

I'm using a project which uses the Eigen library. I've had to already fixed an issue where when using the data types provided by eigen within a STL, I get an align error

> error C2719: '_Val': formal parameter with __declspec(align('16'))
>   won't be aligned

see

- http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicStlContainers.html or -http://www.mrpt.org/Matrices_vectors_arrays_and_Linear_Algebra_MRPT_and_Eigen_classes)

Once this was fixed i could compile and run.

But now at run time I'm getting another error

> Debug Error!
>
> R6010
>
> abort() has been called.

So the code in question references my structure and a vector of my structure (with the eigen specially aligned fix):

```
typedef struct {
    Vector4f v4;
    Matrix4f M4;
    bool b;
} my_struct;

typedef std::vector<my_struct, Eigen::aligned_allocator<my_struct>> my_struct;
```

Then my code fails after a when I try to create a new my_struct after a certain number of iterations (it can sometimes creates the new object, with no problems), other times it fails.

```
for (int i = 0; i<len; i++) {
    Vector4f vec;
    Matrix4f mat;

     my_struct* temp = new my_struct();

}
```

Any ideas?
Tom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without -DNDEBUG, you should have got an assert sending you to this [page](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TopicUnalignedArrayAssert.html). In your case, you should follow [this one](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TopicStructHavingEigenMembers.html). In short, add `EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW` to your structure such that new my_struct call an aligned memory allocator.